# The meaning of walk over to the water-pump

Tags: word-request, difference

We walk over to the water-pump.

Does it make any difference in meaning of this sentence if we omit 'over' in the sentence? I think the 'over' is redundant in the sentence.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain your thinking on this. to=over? What does "over" mean here? etc.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, when you go a short distance on foot, you use walk followed by over to.  For examples:

The policeman walked over to me and asked for my identity.

Walk over here. I want to talk to you.

Answer (score 1):

> We [walk over] **to** the water pump.

Since there's the preposition **to**, the sentence means simply "we approach the water pump by walking to it over some short distance".

You probaly got confused due to the presence of "over": it does not mean "over the water-pump" here because of the presence of "to".

I looked for definitions of "over" and here's the closest one from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/over#Adverb):

> 4. From one position or state to another.
>      *Please pass that **over** to me.‎*
>      *He came **over** to our way of thinking on the new project.‎*
>      *Come **over** and play!‎*
>      *I'll bring **over** a pizza.‎*

Comment: Yes.. and  what is *over* doing there? That might make for a more informative answer...

Comment: @AlanCarmack - I agree, my answer is incomplete..

Comment: It's useful. I'm just curious what *over* is doing here.... Is it *walk over* or *over to* (@Khan?) or *walk/over/to*?